# É possivel fazer um $_Request[""] de outro atributo alem do name=""?

Tags: php, html, data, request

Gostaria de saber se seria possível  fazer um $_Request[""] do atributo de uma tag HTML alem do name="". No meu caso seria data-FotoCapa="teste.jpg".
Dai faria o request do data-FotoCapa.

Valeu!!

Comment: Nem faria sentido. O browser não envia nenhuma propriedade além de name+value.

Comment: SIm, caiu a ficha agora. Nada a ver o que eu perguntei

Comment: E evite request. Explicite sempre se é _GET ou _POST, para evitar confusão e mau uso da sua aplicação.

Comment: @Bacco existe alguma diferença substancial entre o uso explícito como vc diz e o $_REQUEST ? Pergunto pois, sempre tenho essa dúvida entre essas Globais... O que sei é que GET, passa pela URL um nº x de bytes e POST passa camuflado, um nº maior e além disso tem o $_REQUEST.. Nunca entendi direito esse trio...

Comment: @MagicHat o request pega tanto do get quanto do post, mas numa situação normal, você não vai querer esse "tanto faz". Se você tem um form com POST, não tem porque considerar que "se vier por GET tambem serve". Justo o contrário. Pior ainda se por algum motivo vier dos dois. E o request ainda mistura cookies, dependendo da config. Além de tudo tem que ficar tomando cuidado com conflito de nomes.

Comment: Hum... saquei...

Comment: E ainda pode até ter problemas de segurança, vi isso e um post num blog de programação